# How do you secure your sql servers accessed by C# applications

Tags: c#, sql-server, security

Simple and contrived example:

C# desktop application talks to SQL Server database. All orders exist in Orders table.

Application views, creates and amends orders. In this example **a user can only amend their own orders**.

Concerns:

Storage of connection string if using dedicated sql credentials. 
Even if user credentials are used, application security could be bypassed by connecting directly through Excel or Access.

Solutions:

Provide access to SQL through web service/middleware only. Good, but not necessarily viable in this case.

Encrypt connection string in application somewhere. Not hugely secure, security through obscurity.

Secure database by granting access to specific stored procedures, views, etc and no access to actual tables. SP's and views take into account the user's rights/credentials. Pretty awful. Ok for simple examples (Select where user , becomes complicated once you introduce users in different groups, manager relationships, etc.

Alternatives:

How would you approach this?

Thanks

Comment: Remember to sanatize your data inputs: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Even if user credentials are used, application security could be
>   bypassed by connecting directly through Excel or Access

what do you mean? you should not allow users to connect to SQL Server directly or with Excel or Access. They should NOT know the sa or other password.

After this, surely you could encrypt some sections of your app,config so that nobody can see its content.

I would really have the logic that a user can only modify his/her own Orders at the application level. Could be done also in the stored procedures I guess but it depends and more details should be known about this to suggest the best or most appropriate approach.

Comment: I agree, but if they got hold of the credentials, or if they were set up to have access granted by their NT credentials, they could get access.

Comment: I think this is the path that makes the most sense to me.  The application uses SQL auth (connection string in web.config) and access is only available through some DAL which filters results based on the UserID.  Is there some unnecessary vulnerability there?

Comment: Hi nycdan, yes, if the user gets access to the unencrypted connection string they can connect to the database and do anything that that account has rights to do. If the connection is via integrated security, they just need the server name. It won't be a web.config as it's not a web app, so the config file exists on the local machine. Encryption will help with this I guess if we don't use integrated.

Answer (score 3):

Use windows authentication instead of sql authentication.

To allow users to see only their data you can create view and filter data based on the currently logged in user by using [SYSTEM_USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) to get the data for the current user only and deny select permission on the table itself.

Comment: Yeah this I wanted to suggest as well but I think the problem for him is that in this case a user can connect with Access or other tool and modify orders not related to himself. If I have got the question right of course...

Comment: That's is Davide. If we grant them NT rights, they could theoretically just open a connection in Excel or Access and read (and possibly write) any old data they wish.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi. One of the issues I have with this is sometimes a right to edit may be predicated on a user's group access as well. Now I can define those group relationships in sql as well, we actually may end up doing this anyway, but if we end up using, say ActiveDirectory for that things get more compliacated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do row level security in SQL Server (well [you can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966395.aspx), but it's not straightforward). So your only choice to be totally secure is to go through a data-layer which controls access. You can store your credentials encrypted, but that's not totally secure, as you say. It depends what you need.

Comment: Just looking for how others have approached this. Usually I'd go for a service tier, but in this case it's a monolithic application accessing the database directly from the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Well in our application we handle we store the connection string encrypted in a file.
So the user has no direct access to this file.
We also use sql connection only to our database and grant the user for this only.

If you use Windows Credentials to access it and want to prevent any manipulation you can disallow write access to table.
For reading the data you can build queries or access the tables.

For writing/adding/manipulating data you can create stored procedures. One of the parameter is the username. Inside the procedure you build your bussiness logic, impersonate to a user that has write access to finally write/update the data.
There you have your "layer" inside the SQL server.
But I wouldnt suggest to go this way :) It is possible but to many business logic inside the database imho. So the safest way is to find a good encryption class in your language, use sql auth only and store those data inside your code.

Comment: Thanks, that's really appreciated. I agree completely, I hate having that "layer" in sql server itself, it feels so late 90's :)